# Compare Plugin NotePad++ é possível usar no VB6 ou .NET?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-basic-6, dll, notepad++

Eu preciso saber se é possível usar o plugin Compare do Notepad++ nos projetos feitos em VB6 e .NET.

Se sim gostaria de algumas dicas de como posso usá-lo. E não faço ideia de como começar

O sistema que estou fazendo o ajuste, necessita que mande um email toda vez que o usuário altera a descrição de uma ficha. Esse email deve conter a descrição atual e a descrição anterior com as partes alteradas em destaque.
Para entender como seria, este site é um exemplo:

https://text-compare.com/

- Destaca o que foi alterado, o que foi acrescentado e o que foi excluído
  É isso que precisamos... (mas esse site é só um exemplo, não dá para usá-lo no sistema rs)

Eu cheguei a baixar o plugin no github, mas não sei como colocar a referência dele nos projetos. Eu abri projeto Compare pelo Visual Studio e não sei se faço debug (se eu fizer aparece uma mensagem de erro como na imagem)
 ou se adiciono a referência dele nos outros projetos e tentar começar a usar (ai um outro impasse... como vou saber das suas funções).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alguém tiver alguma dica, só pra ter um direcionamento já me ajuda bastante

Comment: Depende do que quer fazer, mas a pergunta não tem informações suficientes para saber o que deseja de fato, falar por cima não ajuda nada, tem que dar detalhes. Não sabemos qual a dificuldade. Enfim, a pergunta tem que estar em uma forma que dê para responder, na forma atual ela é muito ampla.

Answer (score 0):

Me permita dizer que você está equivocado. O plugin **Notepad++ Compare plugin** só funciona para o editor Notepad++, não se aplica instalá-lo no Visual Studio, independente da linguagem utilizada no projeto.

Há duas soluções. Baixar o Notepad++ (grátis) e utilizá-lo para este fim. Ou, se você já versiona fontes com Subversion, o cliente de Subversion **TortoiseSVN** (grátis) possui a ferramenta **TortoiseMerge** para exatamente este fim.